# node-gyp cannot find file within subfolder

Tags: c++, node.js, node-gyp, node.js-addon

I am trying to make a node addon, and I am having issues because I cannot seem to build because I am getting the following error:

> Cannot open include file: 'MagickCore/magick-config.h': No such file or directory

My directory structure looks like this:

```
ImageMagick
  Magick++
    lib
      Magick++.cpp
      Magick++.h
  MagickCore
    magick-config.h
binding.gyp
imagemagick.cc
```

My **binding.gyp** looks like this:

```
{
    'targets': [
        {
            'target_name': 'imagemagick',
            'sources': ['imagemagick.cc'],
            'include_dirs': [
                'ImageMagick/Magick++/lib',
                'ImageMagick/MagickCore',
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and my **imagemagick.cc** looks like this:

```
#include <node.h>
#include <v8.h>
#include <Magick++.h>

namespace demo
{

using v8::FunctionCallbackInfo;
using v8::Isolate;
using v8::Local;
using v8::Object;
using v8::String;
using v8::Value;

void Method(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value> &args)
{
  Isolate *isolate = args.GetIsolate();
  new Magick::Image();
}

void Initialize(Local<Object> exports)
{
  NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "resize", Method);
}

NODE_MODULE(NODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME, Initialize)

}
```

What is causing this issue?

Also, I am using `vscode`, and the settings look like this:

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Win32",
      "includePath": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/ImageMagick/Magick++/**",
        "${workspaceFolder}/ImageMagick/MagickCore/**",
        "C:\\Users\\rnaddy\\.node-gyp\\10.0.0\\include\\node\\**"
      ],
      "defines": [
        "_DEBUG",
        "UNICODE",
        "_UNICODE"
      ],
      "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.14393.0",
      "compilerPath": "C:\\mingw-w64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
      "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
      "browse": {
        "path": [
          "${workspaceFolder}"
        ],
        "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
        "databaseFilename": ""
      }
    }
  ],
  "version": 4
}
```

Comment: Did you install ImageMagick with Node? What version of Imagemagick -- 6 or 7? Be sure that version is compatible with your Node.

Comment: I downloaded the source from github which is what the `ImageMagick` directory is. Do I need to compile that before I build my addon?

Comment: I am not an expert on Node. But I suspect you do. Also you need to be sure that the version of Imagemagick you downloaded (6 or 7) is compatible with your Node.

Comment: It is [imagemagick 7](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick) How would I know that it is compatible? I am new to C++, and I am learning `node-gyp`.

Comment: That is a question to ask to the Node users. But I suspect it does not yet support Imagemagick 7. You can try uninstalling it and installing Imagemagick 6. See https://legacy.imagemagick.org/script/download.php for Imagemagick 6 binaries.

Comment: Okay I tried with [ImageMagick 6](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick6), and still get the same error.

Comment: Okay I figured out what I needed to do... I needed to install imagemagick with development headers, then copy the headers into my project. The error is now gone.